# Выравнивание блоков html

Tags: html, css

В общем, стоит задача сделать галерею для портфолио, блоки располагаются ровно один под одним

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но по макету нужно чтоб они заплывали друг под друга вот так,
подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать? заранее спсибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `column-count`, так мы будем знать, сколько у нас `column` в каждом размере экрана и сможем управлять нашим `responsive` , `column-fill: auto;` даст нам высоту `div` такой, какая она есть, потому что, мы не знаем заранее нашу высоту дива. Пользователь может написать 1 строку или 10 - ответ найдете [пример1](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) и [пример2](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) надеюсь помогло

Answer (score 2):

Просто положите нужные вам блоки в одну колонку.

Если что высоту элементам можно не задавать, это просто для демонстрации.
Пример для демонстрации:

```css
div {
  color: white;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.one {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 150px;
}

.three {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
}

.four {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да но мы ме можем воспользоваться height: 250px; потомушто мы не знаем зарания высоту дива

Comment: column-count и column-fill подходит для решение этой задачи

Comment: @DavidKern Если что высоту можно не задавать, это просто для демонстрации. По поводу `column-count` согласен, но это решение тоже подходит.